# Google Maps GMSPanoramaView api blocked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, panoramas

I'm getting this error:

```
This application has been blocked by the Google Maps API. This might be because of an incorrectly registered key.
```

When I try to set google maps panorama street view.  If I display a regular map view, it works so seems like the key is registered properly.

I followed the directions for a panorama view exactly as per google docs:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

  override func loadView() {
    let panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: .zero)
    self.view = panoView

    panoView.moveNearCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.732, longitude: 150.312))
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was that I needed to link my project in Google Cloud Platform to a billing account.

Once I did that the street view started working correctly.

The standard Google map worked fine without a billing account, which confused me initially.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the delegate for this object. Something like:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

  override func loadView() {
    let panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: .zero)
    panoView.delegate = self
    self.view = panoView

    panoView.moveNearCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.732, longitude: 150.312))
  }
}

extension ViewController: GMSPanoramaViewDelegate {
    func panoramaView(_ view: GMSPanoramaView, error: Error, onMoveNearCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```